# In Docker, is there a way to retrieve the image or layer UUID?

Tags: docker-image

I am looking for a way to retrieve the docker container image UUID and the layers UUID.  I saw the command 'docker images' and 'docker history' but they do not work on the individual image.  Is there a command to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can find some more information about an image if your perform the following commands:

```
$ docker images 

mysql                                           latest              2fd136002c22        8 weeks ago         378.4 MB
```

inspect the imageID or image name

```
$ docker inspect 2fd136002c22
```

output:

```
"RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:4dcab49015d47e8f300ec33400a02cebc7b54cadd09c37e49eccbc655279da90",
                "sha256:5f70bf18a086007016e948b04aed3b82103a36bea41755b6cddfaf10ace3c6ef",
                "sha256:47bce276c5783a6cfc88e0ac368af70909144d04780222d134090dbf08f897aa",
                "sha256:5f70bf18a086007016e948b04aed3b82103a36bea41755b6cddfaf10ace3c6ef",
                "sha256:093c117bc4d3e1cd6e597a89b1648ebb3543be581c61aba80fc41ff6f7ae8e6d",
                "sha256:1028156f10f1a0f79dba5be05e935d5f4588ebe7c25a3581843f7a759a2d7bfb",
...
```

and a lot more information like:

```
"Id": "sha256:2fd136002c22c9017ea24544fc15810aad7d88ab9d53da1063d2805ba0f31e9a",

"Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/mysql": {}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it with a running image:

`$ docker exec youthful_pike cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid
E2F747AF-0000-0000-AA77-B856C9D179D8`